# How to find AssociationProxy declared_attr name in SQLAlchemy from inspection with all_orm_descriptors

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, inspection

I have a SQLAlchemy table class that has an association proxy defined (through a mixin) as below:

```
@declared_attr
def nationality_name(self):
    return association_proxy("nationality", "name")
```

I would like to get the name of this attribute using the SQLAlchemy inspection methods. I've tried the following:

```
for column in mapper.all_orm_descriptors:
    print(column.key)
```

but this gives the name of the the assocation proxy as `_AssociationProxy_nationality_4587917712`, not the name that I actually gave it, which was `nationality_name`. I can't seem to find any other attributes that I could use to get the name it's actually been given.

Is there a way to get this name through SQLAlchemy inspection?

It would probably be possible to fall back on just using `dir` on the table class, but that seems rather fragile (and I'd have to filter out all of the attributes of the class that aren't column names or association proxies).

In searching StackOverflow, I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671854/finding-all-association-proxies-in-a-sqlalchemy-class) where someone says "I worked around it by getting the name of the proxy, and then using getattr" - but I don't know how they got the name. Possibly they weren't using a declared_attr, which might be making this more complicated.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question. However, depending on what you were trying to do, you might be able to get away with substituting the real attribute path instead of using the exact name of the proxy. (For me, I was trying to set things up with Flask-Admin and it was fine taking the attribute path instead). So instead of `assoc_proxy.target_col` you have `target_collection.target_collection_attr.target_col`. You can get the objects for the target collection and the attr on the target collection class via `assoc_proxy.for_class(mapper).attr` which returns a tuple of both.